# Determine the Laplace transform of this piece-wise function

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Determine the Laplace transform of 
$$f(t)=\begin{cases}t, & \textrm{if }& 0<t<2\\
8-3t, & \textrm{if } & 2\leq t<3\\
t-4, & \textrm{if } & 3\leq t\leq4
\\ 0, & \textrm{if } & 4 < t\end{cases}$$

I do not know how to determine the translations. You can help me with a link where you can guide me

Comment: Hint: there will be a bunch of step functions.

Comment: You could take me out a little more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
If 
$$f(t)=\left\lbrace\begin{array}{c l} f_1(t) &{0\leqslant t<c_1},\\ f_2(t) &{c_1\leqslant t<c_2},\\ f_3(t) &{c_2\leqslant t<c_3},\\ \vdots\\ f_{n-1}(t) &{ c_{n-2}\leqslant t<c_{n-1}},\\ f_n(t) &{t\geqslant c_{n-1}}.\end{array}\right.$$ 
then
$$f=f_1+u_{c_1}(f_2-f_1)+u_{c_2}(f_3-f_2)+\cdots+u_{c_{n-1}}(f_n-f_{n-1})$$
where $u_c(t)$ is step function.