# Laplace transform of $\mathcal{L}{tg(t)}$

Tags: laplace-transform

The original question was to find $\mathcal{L}{g(t)}$ from

$$g(t) = \begin{cases} t, 0 \le t < 1 \\ 2-t , 1 \le t \le 2 \\ 0 , t>2 \end{cases} $$

I formed a Heaviside unit step function to solve it,

Here it is -

$g(t) = t [ g(t) - g(t-1) ] + (2-t) [g(t-1) - g(t-2)] + 0 [ g(t-2) - g(t- \infty) ] $

I ended up getting -

$g(t) = t g(t) - 2(t-1)g(t-1) - (2-t)g(t-2) $

Now I have to take Laplace transform of the entire thing, I have to use the formula of $\mathcal{L}{U(t-a)f(t-a)} = e^{-as} F(s)$ to solve the 2nd and 3rd one.

But what about $\mathcal{L}{tg(t)} $ I am not too sure. Can I bring out the t ? For example - 
$t \mathcal {L}{g(t)} $ I think I $t$ is a variable that I need to transform and it’s not a number (when I can do that).

I searched online and found this formula -

$U(t)f(t) = \mathcal{L}{f(t)} $

Do I have to use this then ? Is this the correct formula that I need to use ?

so... $\mathcal {L}{tg(t)} = \mathcal{L}{t} = \frac {1}{S^2} $ ?

Comment: Use https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2846325/108128

Comment: Your step-function expression for $g(t)$ should be $g(t) = t U(t) - 2(t-1)U(t-1) - (2-t)U(t-2)$.

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to write the Laplace transform you need. It is most commonly written

$$ \mathcal{L}\{f(t-a)U(t-a)\}=\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}e^{-as}\tag{1} $$

An alternate version is

$$ \mathcal{L}\{f(t)U(t-a)\}=\mathcal{L}\{f(t+a)\}e^{-as}\tag{2} $$

Using the second rule, for example one has

\begin{eqnarray} \mathcal{L}\{(t-2)U(t-2)\}&=&\mathcal{L}\{(t+2)-2\}e^{-2s}\\
&=&\mathcal{L}\{t\}e^{-2s}\\
&=&\frac{e^{-2s}}{s^2} \end{eqnarray}